# d3js migration mapping - problem recreating an example

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mapping

I am trying to recreate this example: 
http://bl.ocks.org/cingraham/7663357#index.html

The problem is my results are as shown in the picture. 
[image]

The error I get is:

> TypeError: theState[0][0] is null

But since I am just copying the code as is why am I even getting this error? and can anyone help me figure out how to fix it?

Thanks

Edited:

It is here (below) where the code is creating problems... 
Specifically not entering `.attr("stroke-width", function(d, i) {`.

```
function clicked(selected) {

    var selname = selected.id;
    var homex = path.centroid(selected)[0];
    var homey = path.centroid(selected)[1];
    g.selectAll(".goingline")
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", 0)
        .remove()
    g.selectAll(".goingline")
        .data(going)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "goingline")
        .attr("d", function(d, i) {
            var abb = d.abbrev;     
            var finalval = coming[i][selname] - going[i][selname];
            var theState = d3.select("#" + abb); 
            if (!isNaN(finalval)) {
                var startx = path.centroid(theState[0][0].__data__)[0];
                var starty = path.centroid(theState[0][0].__data__)[1];
                if (finalval > 0) {
                    return "M" + startx + "," + starty + " Q" + (startx + homex) / 2 + " " + (starty + homey) / 1.5 + " " + homex + " " + homey;
                } 
                else {
                    return "M" + homex + "," + homey + " Q" + (startx + homex) / 2 + " " + (starty + homey) / 2.5 + " " + startx + " " + starty;
                }
            }
        })
        .call(transition)
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d, i) {
            var finalval = coming[i][selname] - going[i][selname]; console.log("test1")
                return lineSize(parseFloat(Math.abs(finalval)));
        })
        .attr("stroke", function(d, i) {
            var finalval = coming[i][selname] - going[i][selname]; console.log("test1")
            if (finalval > 0) {
                return "#65a89d";
            }
            else {
                return "#a96a46";
            }
        })
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("opacity", 0.5)
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            return toolOver2(d, this);
        })
        .on("mousemove", function(d, i){
            var m = d3.mouse(this);
            mx = m[0];
            my = m[1];
            return toolMove2(mx, my, selname, d.state, coming[i][selname],     going[i][selname]);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            return toolOut2(d, this);
        });
}
```

Comment: Hint: Check your browser console for errors. Check if you are using correct csv values

Comment: Tried doing that too. Can't find the error. 
The only error I get is 'TypeError: theState[0][0] is null, can't access property "__data__" of it'
But then why is it working in the link!

Comment: Look at the "network" tab in debugging tools.  Your re-creation is failing to download the csv files.  My WAG is you aren't running a web-server and are attempting to `d3.csv` from a local file system.

Comment: Yes, I am using the local csv files. But then the flow line is showing. If the csv wasn't downloading the lines wouldn't be showing. The problem is with colour effect and styling.

Comment: Have you copied the css (`fill:none` for the `path`). With the shown code `coming.csv` is loaded parallel to `going.csv`. Best possible that `coming` is not know at the time of constructing the graph

Comment: Just confirming that you continued to use d3v3 for this - d3v4/5 will produce errors regarding `selection[i][j]`.

Comment: Yup, copied everything and I checked. The graph is reading both coming and going. The tooltip also shows the numbers. '
And yup using the d3v3. 

I edited the post to point exactly where I narrowed the issue to.

Comment: I just copied the example to a local server and fixed the `coming.csv` loading and get d3v3 from d3js.org and I do not get errors. On click I get 51 logs of `test1` and `test2`